# Listbox selección multiple VBA EXCEL

Tags: visual-studio, vba

Agradezco el apoyo que me brinde tengo el siguiente código:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Uf As Long
Dim lx As Long
With Hoja1
For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then

Uf = .Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
.Range("O" & Uf) = ListBox1.List(i, 0) 'Columna 1
ListBox1.Selected(i) = False
i = i - 1
Uf = Uf + 1
End If
Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Este código lo que hace es que selecciona *ITEMS* de forma multiple y los va registrando en la columna `"O"` la hoja en Excel; pero necesito que él me pueda almacenar el los *ITEMS* seleccionados, por ejemplo: `2017-2018-2019` en la columna `o` fila `1`; es decir en la misma fila.

Ahorita, como esta desarrollado, me realiza el registro de la siguiente manera

```
2017
2018
2019
```

Estos datos corresponden al cliente *uno* de la hoja ingreso. Al hacerme ese registro así, me está indicado que al cliente `1` se le vendió `x` producto en el 2017, al cliente `2` se le vendió `x` producto en el 2018, etc.

Pero lo real es que la ventas fueron realizadas al cliente 1

Agradezco el apoyo.

Answer (score 2):

Si necesitas que todo quede en la celda `O1`, lo que puedes hacer es ir guardando el nombre de todos los elementos seleccionados en una variable y finalmente asignarle ese valor a la celda.

Tomando como base tu código, podría ser algo como:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim ItemsSeleccionados As String
  ItemsSeleccionados = ""
  With Hoja1
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
      If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
        ItemsSeleccionados = ItemsSeleccionados & "-" & ListBox1.List(i, 0)
        ListBox1.Selected(i) = False
      End If
    Next i
    .Range("O1") = Left(ItemsSeleccionados, Len(ItemsSeleccionados) - 1)
  End With
End Sub
```

Si se seleccionó los items que tienen +:

```
2007 +
2008
2009 + 
2010
```

Esto dejará el valor `2007-2009` en la celda `O1`.

Comment: Buenas noches jachguate agredecido por el tiempo, para darme apoyo yo realice algo parecido al codigo que me estas presentando el codigo me da error de que no conciden los tipos, razon por la cual desarrolle el codigo que envie como consulra ahora el codigo de realizar la misma operaciòn para la fila o 1, o2 ya que son cliente distintos y la ventas se realizaron en diferente periodos

Comment: No tengo Excel a mano para probarlo, el código lo he escrito aquí mismo. ¿Qué línea es la que te da error de que no coinciden los tipos?

Comment: Hice un cambio, pues mi intención era concatenar y estaba utilizando el operador de suma, es mi culpa ya que casi nunca escribo VB.

Comment: no tranquilo lo que me indicastes es correcto me està funcionando cambie los sigo de ++ por && y funciona pero ahora cuando selecciono dos ITEMS en el codigo modificado me realiza lo siguiente: 2017
2017-2018 y lo manejo por seleccion de 3 periodos 2017 2017-2018
2017-2018-2019
estoy agradecido me a funcionado ahora debo hacer que el la variable designada para guardar solo guarde el los items y no me los acumule estoy tratando de ver como lo cambio
el codigo que me facilitastes me ayudo mucho
saludos

Comment: Hola. ¿Seguro que copiaste mi código tal cual? Lo he repasado mentalmente y no veo como podría dar el resultado que mencionas en tu comentario.

Comment: Buen dia el codigo que me facilitastes esta bien solo que el registro lo va hacesr en una solo el la columna o1 creo que no me se pue explicar bien la tengo un total de 240 cluwnte desde la culmna a2 hasta la columna a241 cada cliente se le realizo venta en diferentes periodos la columna o no debe ser fija para todos loa clientes es decir yo evaluar por eso en mi codigo to utilece o & Uf done el rango esla columna o y uf es la ultima fila es decir sinla fila o1 esta registrada el debera el menpermitira evaluar otro cliente y regostrame el periodo  la culmana o para el nuevo cliente

Answer (score 0):

jachguate agradecido por la colaboración que me diste ya realice los ajutes utilizando el codigo que me facilitaste y asi quedo el nuevo codigo empleado para mí vba gracia por su apoyo
saludos cordiales.

```html
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim uf As Long
Dim X As String
Dim Y As String
Dim k As String
   With Hoja1
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
      If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
        X = ListBox1.List(i, 0)
        Y = X & " " & Y
        uf = .Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
      k = Left(Y, Len(Y))
      ListBox1.Selected(i) = False
        
      End If
   
    Next i
       .Range("O" & uf) = k
   End With
End Sub
```